# Unable to query SQL server metadata through linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have a scenario where a user wants to do the following through a linked server:

```
SELECT *
FROM [DBTEST].[AdventureWorks].sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.DatabaseLog');
```

The linked server is configured to use `Be made using this security context` and the linked server login has read access on the `[DBTEST].[AdventureWorks]` database.

The above query does not return any rows when executed through the linked server. However, when I login directly to `DBTEST` using the linked server login and do the following, it does return a row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [AdventureWorks].sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.DatabaseLog')
```

I am confused why it is not working through the linked server and what I need to do in order to fix it.

One more strange thing is even if I grant `sa` rights to the linked server login it still does not return any rows when executed through the linked server.

Both servers are SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@srutzky is correct - this is *not* security related.  As he said, the `OBJECT_ID()` function is operating against the local SQL Server instance, not the remote instance.

If you want to execute the statement unchanged against the remote server, you'd need to run it through dynamic T-SQL, using the following:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 'SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks].sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''dbo.DatabaseLog'');';

EXEC [DBTEST].AdventureWorks.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

This will execute the entire contents of `@sql` at the remote server.

Comment: Riiighht. I keep forgetting about this option :). Does it require any special option to be set to "true" on the Linked Server config? Such as `RPC` and/or `RPC Out`? Either way, +1 as this is also a good option.

Comment: Yes, it depends on `RPC Out` but not `RPC`.

Comment: Thanks Max and srutzky for your help!! I have asked the user to use join solution of sys.objects and sys.schemas.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not security related :-).

In your query, you are selecting from a table on a remote system, but the WHERE condition is using the `OBJECT_ID()` function, which can only see the local instance, and is not running in the scope of the Linked Server connection.

Why don't you try:

```sql
select *
from [DBTEST].[AdventureWorks].sys.objects
where [name] = N'DatabaseLog';
```

And that query makes more sense anyway since you already had the name, so no sense in querying to get the ID from the name just to use the ID in a second query ;-).

If you want / need to also filter on the Schema name, then you will have to add the JOIN to the `[DBTEST].[AdventureWorks].sys.schemas` table as `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` is also local scope only.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I didn't know that OBJECT_ID() function in where clause can't see linked server connection. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SQLPRODDBA No problem at all. If one of these answers worked for you, please do not forget to mark one of them as "accepted". And you are allowed to up-vote either one, or both, regardless of accepting, depending on what you felt was helpful.