# How to modify my existing T-SQL query to work for a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I need to modify my existing `T-SQL` query so that it works for a linked server.

My existing codes are as follows:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
              FROM syscolumns 
              WHERE name like '%SPA%' )
```

I usually connect to the linked server by using the following:

```
Use [MyDatabase]

Select * from [xxx.xx.0.20].[LinkedDatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]
```

I have tried the answers given here (but it's still not working): [Unable to query SQL server metadata through linked server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116147/unable-to-query-sql-server-metadata-through-linked-server)

Here's my try (even though I don't quite understand why I need to put that dot (.) in sysobjects compared to my existing codes shown above):

```
   USE [MyDatabase]
    
    SELECT name 
    FROM [xxx.xx.0.20].[LinkedDatabaseName].sys.objects
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
                  FROM syscolumns 
                  WHERE name like '%SPA%' )
```

I get the following error message: "Invalid column name 'id'."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to make all references in your query point to the table on the other side of the linked server.

i.e.:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
    
SELECT name 
FROM [xxx.xx.0.20].[LinkedDatabaseName].sys.objects o
WHERE o.object_id IN ( SELECT c.object_id 
              FROM [xxx.xx.0.20].[LinkedDatabaseName].sys.columns c
              WHERE c.[name] like '%SPA%' );
```

Your current version of the query is looking at `sys.objects` from the remote database, and `syscolumns` from the local database in the current context.

You should avoid using `syscolumns` since that is a deprecated object.  Instead, use `sys.columns`.  The `id` column you're looking for is actually `object_id`, or for the column id, it is `column_id`.

Since you are referencing a database directly via four-part naming through a linked server, the `USE [MyDatabase]` in the first line is irrelevant.